# SQL - Multiply values in same table

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2005

I have the following code:

```html
SELECT ConsumerID, Product,
       (frequency * Product_Value) as Value_productA
       (frequency * Product_Value) as Value_productB
       (frequency * Product_Value) as value_productC
From Table1
```

The table1 looks like that:

```html
ConsumerID | Product | Product_value | frequency | value_productA | value_productB | value_productC
-----------------------------------------------------------------
001 | productA | 5$ | 2 | | | |
001 | productB | 7$ | 4 | | | |
001 | productC | 9$ | 6 | | | |
002 | productA | 5$ | 2 | | | |
002 | productB | 7$ | 4 | | | |
002 | productC | 9$ | 6 | | | |


Expected Bevaviour:

ConsumerID | Product | Product_value | frequency | value_productA | value_productB | value_productC
-----------------------------------------------------------------
001 | productA | 5$ | 2 |10$ |    |    |
001 | productB | 7$ | 4 |    |28$ |    |
001 | productC | 9$ | 6 |    |    |54$ |
002 | productA | 5$ | 2 | 10$|    |    |
002 | productB | 7$ | 4 |    |28$ |    |
002 | productC | 9$ | 6 |    |    |54$ |


Current behaviour:

ConsumerID | Product | Product_value | frequency | value_productA | value_productB | value_productC
-----------------------------------------------------------------
001 | productA | 5$ | 2 |10$ |10$ |10$ |
001 | productB | 7$ | 4 |28$ |28$ |28$ |
001 | productC | 9$ | 6 |54$ |54$ |54$ |
002 | productA | 5$ | 2 |10$ |10$ |10$ |
002 | productB | 7$ | 4 |28$ |28$ |28$ |
002 | productC | 9$ | 6 |54$ |54$ |54$ |
```

The idea is to calculate the value for each client & product - Meaning frequency*product_value. The example code calculates the SUM correctly but writes it in every fiels instead of only in the value_productX field.

Answer (score 0):

You need some conditional logic, such as `case`:

```
SELECT ConsumerID, Product,
       (case when product = 'productA' then (frequency * Product_Value) end) as Value_productA
       (case when product = 'productB' then (frequency * Product_Value) end) as Value_productB
       (case when product = 'productC' then (frequency * Product_Value) end) as value_productC
From Table1;
```

Normally, when a similar question is asked, the goal is to get one row per `consumerid`.  If that is the case, you want aggregation:

```
select ConsumerID,
       sum(case when product = 'productA' then (frequency * Product_Value) end) as Value_productA
       sum(case when product = 'productB' then (frequency * Product_Value) end) as Value_productB
       sum(case when product = 'productC' then (frequency * Product_Value) end) as value_productC
From Table1
group by ConsumerID
```

Comment: Great, that worked and solved the issue! Thanks a lot AGAIN